# Node.js - Returning response from https.request() showing weird symbols

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making an experimental web proxy in Node.js. A lot of websites work like normal even Discord.com. The problem is on [this website](https://startpage.com).

For some odd reason, it's showing a lot of weird symbols instead of the website. But if I go on any image on that site the images work fine. I would love the help. I would also prefer to use regular HTTPS / HTTP modules.

By the way, the commented out parts are for a WebSocket proxy so discard that.

```
    const express = require('express'),
    app = express(), 
    WebSocket = require('ws'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    https = require('https'),
    http = require('http');


    btoa = (str) => {
        str = new Buffer.from(str).toString('base64');
        return str;
      };
    
      atob = (str) => {
        str = new Buffer.from(str, 'base64').toString('utf-8');
        return str;
      };

      const server_options = {
        key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/default.key'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/default.crt')
      }

    const server = https.createServer(server_options, app);

    //server.on('upgrade', function upgrade(req, socket, head) {

     // const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ 
       // server: server
      // });

     // wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
        
       // console.log(req.url.slice(1))

       // const client = new WebSocket(req.url.slice(1));
  
        //ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
   
          //  client.send(message)
  
       // });
      
       // client.on('message', function incoming(data) {
         // ws.send(data)
       // })

       // ws.on('error', function incoming(data) {
         //   client.send(data)
       // });

       // client.on('error', function incoming(data) {
         // ws.send(data)
        //});

     // }); 

    //});

  

    app.use('/', async(req, res, next) => {
    var proxy = {};
    proxy.url = `https://www.startpage.com${req.url}`;
    proxy.url = {
        href: proxy.url,
        hostname : proxy.url.split('/').splice(2).splice(0, 1).join('/'),
        origin : proxy.url.split('/').splice(0, 3).join('/'),
        encoded_origin : btoa(proxy.url.split('/').splice(0, 3).join('/')),
        path : '/' + proxy.url.split('/').splice(3).join('/'),
        protocol : proxy.url.split('\:').splice(0, 1).join(''), 
    }


    proxy.requestHeaders = req.headers;

    proxy.requestHeaders.host = proxy.url.hostname;
    

    delete proxy.requestHeaders['accept-encoding']

    proxy.requestHeaders['referer'] = proxy.url.href;

    proxy.requestHeaders['origin'] = proxy.url.origin;

    proxy.options = {
        method: req.method,
        headers: proxy.requestHeaders,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }

    if (proxy.url.protocol == 'https') { proxy.protocol = https; }
    else {proxy.protocol = http};

    proxy.sendRequest = proxy.protocol.request(proxy.url.href, proxy.options, server_res => {
        var body = [], redirect = false, redirect_value = '';

        server_res.on('data', (chunk) => {
             body.push(Buffer.from(chunk, 'binary'))
        });
       
        var ct = 'text/plain';
        Object.entries(server_res.headers).forEach(([header_name, header_value]) => {
            if (header_name.startsWith('content-encoding') || header_name.startsWith('x-') || header_name.startsWith('cf-') || header_name.startsWith('strict-transport-security') || header_name.startsWith('content-security-policy')) {
                delete server_res.headers[header_name];
            }
            if (header_name.startsWith('location') || header_name.startsWith('Location')) {
                redirect = true; redirect_value = header_value;
                delete server_res.headers[header_name];
            }
            if (header_name == 'content-type') ct = header_value;
        });

          if (ct == null || typeof ct == 'undefined') ct = 'text/html';
        if (redirect == true) { return res.redirect(307, '/' + redirect_value);  };

            server_res.on('end', () => {
                body = Buffer.concat(body)
                res.contentType(ct)
                res.set(server_res.headers);
                res.status(server_res.statusCode)
                res.send(body)
            });
      });

      proxy.sendRequest.on('error', err => {
         res.send(err.toString())
      });

      if (req.method == 'POST') {
        req.raw_body = '';
        req.str_body = '';
        req.on('data', chunk => {
             req.raw_body += chunk.toString(); // convert Buffer to string
        });
        req.on('end', () => {
             req.str_body = req.raw_body;
             proxy.sendRequest.write(req.str_body);
             proxy.sendRequest.end();
        });
     } else proxy.sendRequest.end();
});
server.listen('9000')
```

[image: weird symbols]

Comment: What do these weird symbol look like? Can you provide picture?

Comment: I just did! I hope you can help!

Comment: What is the value of `str`, have you confirmed its base-64 encoded ? Post the value of `str`

Comment: That's very much expected if you just delete the `content-encoding` header from the response and still serve the raw data.

Comment: I get Content-Encoding error when I don't delete it!!!

Comment: @Alloy-Dev did you ever find out the reason?